# How to recode values based on duplicate values in another dataset

Tags: r, recode

I am working with the following data. We can call it `x`

```
   New_Name_List               Old_Name_List
1     bumiputera        bumiputera (muslims)
2     bumiputera          bumiputera (other)
3 non bumiputera non bumiputera (indigenous)
4        chinese                     chinese
```

The goal is to recode data in another data object that looks like this. We can call it `y`

```
  EPR_country_code EPR_country           EPR_group_lower_2
1              835      Brunei        bumiputera (muslims)
2              835      Brunei          bumiputera (other)
3              835      Brunei non bumiputera (indigenous)
4              835      Brunei                     chinese
```

If `x$New_Name_List` has duplicate values I want the `x$Old_Name_List` values in the new column `y$EPR_group_lower_3`.

If `x$New_Name_List` has unique values, I want the `x$New_Name_List` in the new column, `y$EPR_group_lower_3`.

So that the data will look like this at the end:

```
  EPR_country_code EPR_country           EPR_group_lower_2  EPR_group_lower_3
1              835      Brunei        bumiputera (muslims)  bumiputera (muslims)
2              835      Brunei          bumiputera (other)  bumiputera (other)
3              835      Brunei non bumiputera (indigenous)  non bumiputera
4              835      Brunei                     chinese  chinese
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `ifelse` and select values from `Old_Name_List` or `New_Name_List` based on duplicate values in `New_Name_List`.

```
y$EPR_group_lower_3 <- with(x, ifelse(duplicated(New_Name_List) | 
        duplicated(New_Name_List, fromLast = TRUE), Old_Name_List, New_Name_List))
y

#  EPR_country_code EPR_country           EPR_group_lower_2    EPR_group_lower_3
#1              835      Brunei        bumiputera (muslims) bumiputera (muslims)
#2              835      Brunei          bumiputera (other)   bumiputera (other)
#3              835      Brunei non bumiputera (indigenous)       non bumiputera
#4              835      Brunei                     chinese              chinese
```

---

Or find the indices where the values are duplicated and replace only those.

```
y$EPR_group_lower_3 <- x$New_Name_List
inds <- with(x, duplicated(New_Name_List) | duplicated(New_Name_List, fromLast = TRUE))
y$EPR_group_lower_3[inds] <- x$Old_Name_List[inds]
```

**data**

```
x <- structure(list(New_Name_List = c("bumiputera", "bumiputera", 
"non bumiputera", "chinese"), Old_Name_List = c("bumiputera (muslims)", 
"bumiputera (other)", "non bumiputera (indigenous)", "chinese"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

y <- structure(list(EPR_country_code = c(835L, 835L, 835L, 835L), 
EPR_country = c("Brunei", "Brunei", "Brunei", "Brunei"), 
EPR_group_lower_2 = c("bumiputera (muslims)", "bumiputera (other)", 
"non bumiputera (indigenous)", "chinese")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```